# Using wget in a crontab to run a PHP script

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wget, cron

I set up a cron job on my Ubuntu server. Basically, I just want this job to call a php page on an other server. This php page will then clean up some stuff in a database. So I tought it was a good idea to call this page with wget and then send the result to /dev/null because I don't care about the output of this page at all, I just want it to do its database cleaning job.
So here is my crontab:

```
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/wget -q --post-data 'pass=mypassword' http://www.mywebsite.com/myscript.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

(I post a password to make sure no one could run the script but me). It works like a charm except that wget writes each time an empty page in my user directory: the result of downloading the php page.

I don't understand why the result isn't send to /dev/null ? Any idea about the problem here?
Thanks you very much!

Comment: Use -O with `wget`, or `curl` instead of `wget`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

wget's output to STDOUT is it trying to make a connection, showing progress, etc.

If you don't want it to store the saved file, use the  `-O file` parameter:

```
/usr/bin/wget -q --post-data -O /dev/null 'pass=mypassword' http://www.mywebsite.com/myscript.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Checkout the [wget manpage](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#index-number-of-retries-26). You'll also find the `-q` option for completely disabling output to STDOUT (but offcourse, redirecting the output as you do works too).

Answer (score 5):

```
wget -O /dev/null ....
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

you can mute wget output with the --quiet option

```
wget  --quiet    http://example.com
```